# Where is my Code First database?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have a code first DbContext that is supposed to be creating a new DB, but after several tries, the DB doesn't exist, and I am getting a Sequence contains no elements error on `ctx.Statuses.ToList()` in the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ctx = new EtbDbContext();
    EtbDbContext.Init();

    var s = ctx.Statuses.ToList();
    var l = ctx.Logins.ToList();
    var u = ctx.Users.ToList();
}
```

The `Init()` method says:

```
public static void Init()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EtbDbContext>());
}
```

When I get the error and check my connection string in the Immediate window, it is as configured and expected:

> ?ctx.Database.Connection {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection}
>   ..
>       ConnectionTimeout: 15
>       Database: "EtbCodeFirst"
>       DataSource: "BRADY-PC"
>       ServerVersion: 'ctx.Database.Connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       State: Closed

No such DB exists on the data source BRADY-PC, so I should be getting a connection error before even trying to query the DB. I am as peeved as confused and really hope someone can help before I'm driven back to DB first development today.

I have also checked my (localdb) and still no DB. There is nowhere else for even rogue EF code to create a damned DB.

Comment: Can you move `EtbDbContext.Init();` upwards in your `Main` method so that it is the very first line and test again? I'm not sure if it matters but it looks strange to create a context instance before setting the initializer.

Comment: @Slauma Good point. I have used it like this without trouble before, but maybe I just never noticed. I will try your suggestion soon as I can.

Comment: definitely a wrong order of things (in the best case shouldn't do anything) as @Slauma noticed. Also what is your config in the app.config - connection string (naming) and 'defaultConnectionFactory' if any - and which provider are you targeting (to avoid wrong versions). Also could you try running new EtbDbContext(connectionstring) - that usually works and helps you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Call .Init **before** opening your context...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EtbDbContext.Init();
    using (var ctx = new EtbDbContext())
    {
        var s = ctx.Statuses.ToList();
        var l = ctx.Logins.ToList();
        var u = ctx.Users.ToList();
    }
}
```